# RegExp alphanumeric String + Special Letters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

First question : I want to replace all characters other than alphanumeric and Special Letters. For example , `somestringğüş iöç123456!@#$%^&*()_+` to `somestringğüş iöç123456`

Second: For example , `some---example--long-string` to `some-example-long-string`

I do not really know regexp , so I need 2 simple regexp strings.Thank you

Comment: NO, I am just trying to create some share.php script (as iframe modal box . part of my project).

Comment: No offense. You gave both the question and a hint for the answer.
Using Regexp you can replace the special characters.

Comment: *if it looks like homework, if it reads like homework, it must be a homework*. Please, leave tags alone.

Comment: I explained that , This is not homework This is part of my own project. If you want to feel like this is homework , There is no need to special 'homework' tag , please do not edit my question , If you want to feel it like homework do it yourself. Unfortunately , I can not understand Homework misconception of ST Community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First.** It matches any character that is not alphanumeric, whitespace or non-ascii, and replaced them with the empty string.

```
str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s\x80-\uFFFF]+/gi, '');
```

There are no unicode-classes that I can use, so either I include all unicode characters, or list the ones that are not letters, digits nor whitespace.

**Second.** It matches any sequence of two or more dashes, and replaces them with a single dash.

```
str.replace(/-{2,}/g, '-');
```

Comment: `ğ` and `ş` are outside of the `\x80-\xff` block.

Comment: You can combine these replaces: `str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s\x80-\uFFFF]+/gi, '-')`

Comment: @Gumbo: Not quite, because that would introduce a dash in `a###b` instead. That may be okay, of course, but that's not what's specified. It is possible to do this in one regex nonetheless, but I'm not sure if it's worth it, and I'm not sure what OP wants `a#-#-#-#b` to become (i.e. `a---b` or `a-b`?)

Answer (score 3):

```
 /* 1. */   return x.replace(/[!@#$%^&*()_+]/g, '');
 /* 2. */   return x.replace(/-{2,}/g, '-');
```

Comment: two or more hyphens should be replaced with empty string.

Comment: You were right that first time: that should be `replace(/-{2,}/g, '-')`. `some---example` --> `some-example`

Comment: @Silent & @Kobi : Actually There is no difference , They both do same thing . I just tested.

Comment: @oguz - I don't see how that's possible, that'd change `a---b` to `ab`, not `a-b`.

Comment: @Kobi: you're right, @Kenny: sorry, don't know what was I thinking